# Laravel 4.2 - Load a data array from database in app/config/app.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, configuration

I have language table in my database that contains list of available languages:

---

```
id|language

1|en

2|de

3|lv

4|de
```

....

I want to load array a list with available languages in my app/config/app.php file and add it as additional parameter:

`'languages' => array('en', 'ru', 'lv', 'de'…..)`

Is there some proper way how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for sure. You can use `Config::set('app.languages', array('en', 'ru', 'lv', 'de'…..))` to set the config dynamically. Doing it directly in the config file won't work, since all the database classes aren't available at that time.

### But

Why even bother using the config?! In my opinion, config files are for *static* config that get's set inside files. And I wouldn't mix it with config data loaded from the database. Instead I would create a model `Language`

```
class Language extends Eloquent {
    // this assumes your table is called "languages"
}
```

To get your array of languages, just do

```
Language::all()->lists('language');
```